# How can I ask for a user's contact information?

Tags: phrase-requests, ambiguity, modal-verbs

We have an app in which users will win prizes, and we will be contacting them by email to send them their prizes. In the dialog requesting the user's email address, I've written this text:

> Please enter your email address so we could contact you:

This sounds strange to me. However, I'm struggling to come up with something better.

Answer (score 2):

'Could' implies the conditional. So you 'could contact' them in what circumstances?

I suppose you could just say '...so we can contact you', but you imply that you will only contact them if they have won a prize. In that case you need to say: '...so we can contact you in the event you are lucky', or something like that.

Comment: I'm asking only after the prize is won.

Comment: @JuozasKontvainis Well you definitely don't want 'could' because that is conditional on something. Simply '...so we can contact you' is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

> "Please enter your email address so that we can contact you:"
>
> "Please enter your email address to enable us to contact you:"

Answer (score 1):

You should rephrase your question as:

> *We have an app in which users **could** win prizes, and in which case we **would** contact them by email, to enable them to receive their prizes.*

Otherwise, is your app meant to let everyone win prizes?

When you have straightened your understanding of your situation and motivation, it would naturally come to you that

1. Regardless of their disposition, you want their email IDs.
2. Prizes are merely a way to encourage them to reveal/supply their email IDs.
3. Therefore, do not give the impression that they should not supply their email IDs if they are not interested in prizes.
4. Most users prefer leaving comments and suggestions than receiving prizes.

Which then calls for a careful deliberation of your UI design and presentation.

Gradually reveal these one point at a time, during app start-up.

1. Thank you for using ZZZApp.
   Do you want to help us improve ZZZApp?
2. So leave a comment.
   And your email ID, so that we could respond to you.
3. You can win prizes too.
   The weekly prize is listed at {url}.
   Enter your email to win prizes.
4. Remember, don't forget to continually update us on how you are using ZZZApp.
   You can also login with your email ID to leave your comments at {url}.

   ```
   Comments box

   Email ID box

   [Submit button is not enabled until email ID is filled in]  
   ["Skip to app" button] Don't show this screen again [check box]
   ```

Which would require your app residing on the user's device to at least have an SMTP library embedded, to be able to send that email to your email acct.

Naturally, users would realise that they need to supply the email id if they wish to be contacted for the possible prize.

Comment: I agree that it would be most natural to ask for email when setting up the app. However our app is already distributed, we don't have users emails and the prizes for existing users are a new functionality that we are adding.